# Arreglos en python

Tags: python, array, numpy

Necesito agregar datos en un arreglo bidimencional por medio de un for, tengo el problema que al momento de imprimir solo imprime el ultimo dato ingresado en el for, empiezo a conocer el lenguaje y se me ah complicado entender el uso de arreglos a comparación de lenguajes como C.
mi código es el siguiente, cabe destacar que estoy utilizando la librería numpy.
El objetivo de mi codigo es encontrar la distancia mas corta para 10 puntos generados aleatoriamente e imprimir los 3 puntos mas cercanos.

```py
    import numpy as np

    B=10*np.random.random((10,2))
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    pr=10*np.random.random((1,1))
    indexmin=-1
    distmin=0
    for i in range(0,10):
        d=np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(np.subtract(B[i],pr),2.0)))
        l=[[i],[d]]

        if(i==0):
            distmin=d
            indexmin=i
        if(d<distmin):
            distmin=d
            indexmin=i

    print(l)



    plt.plot(B[:,1],B[:,0],'ro')
    plt.plot(pr[0],pr[0],'b*')
    plt.axis([0,10,0,10])
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En cada iteración del `for` reasignas a `l` una nueva lista, por lo que como es de esperar al terminar el `for`,  `l` apunta a la lista creada en la última iteración del ciclo.

Si quieres que `l` sea un array de NumPy, debes declararlo antes del `for` para reservar memoria y luego usar indizado para asignar los valores en el `for`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


B = 10 * np.random.random((10, 2))
pr = 10 * np.random.random((1, 1))

l = np.empty(10)
indexmin = -1
distmin = 0

for i in range(0, 10):
    d = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(np.subtract(B[i], pr), 2.0)))
    l[i] = d

    if i == 0:
        distmin = d
        indexmin = i

    if d < distmin:
        distmin = d
        indexmin = i
```

Si quisieras que fuera una lista Python, puedes inicializarla primero mediante:

```
l = [0] * 10
```

y dentro del `for` hacer lo mismo que antes o usar `list.append` directamente:

```
l = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    ...
    l.append(d)
```

No obstante, cuando uses NumPy aprovecha las posibilidades de vectorización que ofrece en vez de recurrir a ciclos. Es mucho más simple y eficiente hacer los siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


B = 10 * np.random.random((10, 2))
pr = 10 * np.random.random((1, 1))

l = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(np.subtract(B, pr), 2.0), axis=1))
indexmin = np.argmin(l)
distmin = l[indexmin]
```